# How do I extract real and imaginary parts from 1000+ eigenvalues to test for stable nodes, unstable nodes, saddle, focus, etc.?

Tags: r, math, calculus

I am new to this program and have never programmed before. I am not sure how to proceed at all when it comes to extracting the real and imaginary numbers from the eigenvalues (generated from 1000 2x2 matrices) and I don't know how to test for stable/unstable nodes, stable/unstable focus, centers, and saddle points.

I have already generated the 1000 2 by 2 matrices and generated every single eigenvalue from them. I have also plotted these eigenvalues. However, I don't know if my next bunch of coding is even on the right track.

```
for(i in 1:k){
  z=runif(4,min=-10,max=10)

points(Re(lambda[1]),Im(lambda[1]))
points(Re(lambda[2]),Im(lambda[2]))
points(Re(lambda[1]),Im(lambda[2]))
points(Re(lambda[2]),Im(lambda[1]))
```

The top section is part of the code I used to generate my matrices with random numbers from -10 to 10. I tried extracting the real and imaginary numbers like this but do I need to add more to the list of points. Also, after this how would I even test for the nodes and other points.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket somewhere, and we don't have access to any of your data to be able to run this code, and can't see your output. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that's easy for folks to help with.

Comment: My close vote as a typo is for not correcting the already identified syntactic error. I can always reverse it if that problem (and the lack of a [MCVE]) are corrected.